# User does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

**What I wanna do is:**

1.SSO with wso2 Identity server 5.1.0 and wso2 API manager 1.10.0 (done)

reference : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+SAML2

2.Login wso2 API manager 1.10.0 via Facebook credential (done)

reference : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/How+To%3A+Login+to+the+Identity+Server+using+Facebook+Credentials

3.After logging in API-M via Facebook account, I wanna deploy sample API (fail)

**API-M logs :**

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager} -  Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 4258a2ab-ce6e-468d-9855-56ff70d20ad8. Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata. {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.GovernanceArtifactManager}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.


ERROR GovernanceArtifactManager Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 4258a2ab-ce6e-468d-9855-56ff70d20ad8. Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Error while performing registry transaction operation {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider}
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 4258a2ab-ce6e-468d-9855-56ff70d20ad8. Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.


ERROR UserAwareAPIProvider Error while performing registry transaction operation
org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 4258a2ab-ce6e-468d-9855-56ff70d20ad8. Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.


ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-design.ajax.add:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in adding API :CalculatorAPI (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#107)

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in adding API :CalculatorAPI

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 4258a2ab-ce6e-468d-9855-56ff70d20ad8. Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.


ERROR add:jag org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in adding API :CalculatorAPI (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#107)

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in adding API :CalculatorAPI

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.exception.GovernanceException: Failed to add artifact: artifact id: 4258a2ab-ce6e-468d-9855-56ff70d20ad8. Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add new resource. User sbyangtw@yahoo.com.tw does not have authorization to update the collection /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata.
```

And I set the permission of the role everyone to be All permissions.

I try to go to API-M Store and create a new application, it's done but still can't deploy API to Publisher.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API manager uses a registry listener to give permission to its own registry paths. But when you create an user and the roles from IS side that listener will not get execute. Hence, those registry paths will not be assigned those required permissions for that particular user.
There are two workarounds.

1 You can create users and roles through API manager console.

2. You can install API manager features on IS.

Comment: After I set Identity server as the key manager of API-M, it's working now. Thanks